# ¿cómo puedo desinstalar pip en python? (Windows)

Tags: python, pip

Tengo un problema y es que para usar Django descargué e instalé Python 3.5.0 y según la documentación oficial de Django tengo que tener pip que es un manejador de paquetes. El problema es que busqué cómo descargar el pip y lo hice en un archivo que descargué desde esta página: `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` y lo guardé en el escritorio, luego ejecuté el comando `python get-pip.py` en el escritorio y parecía que se estaba instalando, pero luego me mandó una excepción y me dijo que ya estaba usando pip, pero que podía actualizarlo con un comando, entonces usé ese comando para actualizarlo y me manda el mismo error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero saber cómo desinstalar pip y cómo volver a instalarlo porque así no se puede usar y necesito usar Django :(. Por lo visto la versión de Python que estoy usando ya trae pip listo para usarlo o no?

Comment: En Windows `pip` ya viene incluido por defecto con la instalación de Python. Si no te deja actualizar es porque **no tienes permisos de escritura** en el directorio de instalación de Python. Deberías instalar Python en un directorio no protegido del sistema , en Win10 se suele instalar por defecto en  `C:\Users\TuUsuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python` si mal no recuerdo. Otra opción en tu caso, es que inicies la consola (CMD) en modo administrador (aunque no es lo recomendado).De todas formas te recomiendo que uses un entorno virtual para tu proyecto e instalar en el lo que necesites.

Comment: Eso intento hacer, pero se supone que el virtualenv se instala con el pip y me está dando errores, por eso quiero desinstalarlo para volver a instalarlo

Comment: No tienes que desinstalar, como te comento tu problema es que no tienes permisos en ese directorio. Necesitas permisos de administrador para modificar `Program files` en versiones recientes de Win. Igual que no te deja actualizar pip lo normal es que tampoco te deje instalar otras librerías. Lo más simple es que instalaras Python en un directorio de tu usuario. Te recomiendo que uses Python 3.5.4 (última versión de 3.5 con bugs corregidos si no quieres usar la 3.6). Además puedes usar [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) de la stdlib para el entorno como alternativa.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias por ayudarme. Desinstalé la versión de Python que tenía y voy a instalar la 3.5.4. Por favor sigue guiándome en el proceso, no he podido usar Django y lo necesito. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Intenta abrir una consola con permisos de admin,  y corres los comandos. si no te funciona, Docker te puede servir,  y te evitas dolores de cabeza en el futuro. La verdad usar Window trae sus problemas. ya los veras cuando avances en tu proyecto.